# Easy Facebook Android SDK - NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, android-anr-dialog, networkonmainthread

I have been Using this SDK http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/ to integrate Facebook in my App.
I only want to update a statur from my App. It worked great using this class in Android API 10. Running it on phone with API 15 gives me a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. here my code:

```
package com.my.wod;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import com.main.xfit.R;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.facebook.android.*;

import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

public class PostFaceBookStatus extends Activity {


private static final String APP_ID = "ID OF MY APP";
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {"publish_stream" };

private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
    private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
    private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

private Facebook facebook;
private String messageToPost;

public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
        editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
        facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return facebook.isSessionValid();
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    restoreCredentials(facebook);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.facebook);

    String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), facebookMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (facebookMessage == null){
         facebookMessage = "SUNDAY 120506 2012 CrossFit Games Regional: Individual Event 4 For time: 135 pound Back squat, 50 reps 40 Pull-ups 135 pound Shoulder-to-overhead, 30 reps 85 pound Front squat, 50 reps 40 Pull-ups 85 pound Shoulder-to-overhead, 30 reps 65 pound Overhead squat, 50 reps 40 Pull-ups 65 pound Shoulder-to-overhead, 30 reps";
    }
    //messageToPost = facebookMessage;
    messageToPost = "Post random shit" ;
}

public void doNotShare(View button){
    finish();
}
public void share(View button){
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndPostToWall();
    }
    else {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
}

public void loginAndPostToWall(){
     facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}

public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message);
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            try {
                facebook.request("me");
                String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
                }
            else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
                }
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                finish();
    }
}

class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(facebook);
        if (messageToPost != null){
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
        finish();
    }
}

private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't run network operations on the UI thread, and if you think it is is the API code doing it, then you'll have to wrap the API call's in a Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run network operations on the UI thread, and if you think it is is the API code doing it, then you'll have to wrap the API call's in a Thread.

Looks like this line is using the network:

```
 String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

You need to do long running tasks on a worker thread.

You used to get an ANR (Activity Not Responsding) but ICS is a little cleverer and kicks you off before this happens.

Get reading:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask < This is one possible alternative answer

Comment: Hi,great answer worked perfectly. I was confused because running this exact class works fine on Android API 10.. The AsynkTask solved the problem thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To make it work for API level 10 and higher i just employed and AsyncTask and it Worked!!
Use the below code:

//make this global declaration
private Facebook mFacebook;

```
private class FbLoginAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(ConstantsCtc.DIALOG_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // facebooklogin();
        return getFacebookData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User u) {
        super.onPostExecute(u);
        // your facebook information is in User bean 'u'.

    }

}

public User getFacebookData() {
    User u = new User();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonME = null;
        JSONObject jsonfrnd = null;
        try {
            jsonME = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
            // jsonfrnd =
            // Util.parseJson(mFacebook
            // .request("me/friends"));
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            u = null;
        }
        Log.w("fbjsonMe", " *\n  " + jsonME);
        // Log.e("fbjsonfrnds", " *\n  " + jsonfrnd);

        String mUserId = jsonME.getString("id");
        String mUserName = jsonME.getString("first_name");
        String mUseremail = jsonME.getString("email");
        String birthday = jsonME.getString("birthday");
        String gender = jsonME.getString("gender");
        String full_name = jsonME.getString("name");

        // Log.w("UserName", mUserName + " *  " + mUseremail + " *\n  "
        // + jsonME);

        // calculate age
        String ag[] = birthday.split("/");
        int y = Integer.parseInt(ag[2]);// get birth year
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int age = currentyear - y;

        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
            gender = "0";
        else
            gender = "1";

        u.setUserId(mUserId);
        u.setUserFullName(full_name);
        u.setEmail(mUseremail);
        u.setAge(age + "");
        u.setGender(gender);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        u = null;
    }
    return u;
}

// then make a call to below method form your activity's button click or
// else

public void facebookLogin() {
    this.mFacebook = new Facebook(appId);// give your appId

    if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        new FbLoginAsync().execute();
    } else {
        SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthSucceed() {
                new FbLoginAsync().execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthFail(String error) {
                showDialogCustome("Error in Facebook Login, please try again later");
                Log.e("onAuthFail", "onAuthFail");
            }
        };
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);
        mFacebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions,
                Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}
```

I hope this solves your problem. let me know